# Unable to update from repository : CCRC

Tags: plugins, repository, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I am trying to update my view using 'update from repository'. I get an error in a window 'Problem performing ClearCase operation'. I am using ClearCase plugin with SOATest. It was all working fine till pervious day but for some reason its not working today. I am rather new to ClearCase and I have tried to check the logs. I am not sure if I am missing out something.

Answer (score 0):

None of the recent [ClearTeam 8.0.x IBM Fixes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023148) involve the "update from repository", so you can try and:

- check if you are still connected to the CCRC server
- [set up debug tracing for the ClearCase Remote Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413762) (if you are using a CCRC 7.x
- asking the admin of the CCRC server to check the logs on the server side.